# Issue doing map and filter on Redux ORM QuerySet

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, jestjs, redux-orm

I am doing the tutorial for redux-orm [here](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm-primer/) I need to call `map` on a QuerySet instance within my test.

The original test in the repo is [here](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm-primer/blob/master/app/test/testModels.js#L84)

This is how I create the `Todo`:

```
const todoTags = 'testing,nice,cool'
const user = session.User.first()
const userId = user.getId()

const action = {
  type: CREATE_TODO,
  payload: {
    text: todoText,
    tags: todoTags,
    user: userId
  }
}

const { Todo, Tag, User } = applyActionAndGetNextSession(schema, state, action)
```

My code looks like this:

```
const newTodo = Todo.last()
console.log(newTodo.tags.forEach, newTodo.tags.map)
console.log('Print all tags')
newTodo.tags.forEach(tag => {
  console.log('Prints a tag')
  console.log(tag)
})

newTodo.tags.map(tag => {
  console.log('Prints a tag 2')
  console.log(tag)
  return tag
})

expect(newTodo.text).toEqual(todoText)
expect(newTodo.user.getId()).toEqual(userId)
expect(newTodo.done).toBeFalsy()
const newTodoTags = newTodo.tags.map(tag => tag.name)
console.log(newTodoTags)
expect(newTodoTags).toEqual(['testing','nice','cool'])
```

The `Tag` model looks like:

```
Tag.backend = {
  idAttribute: 'name'
}
```

I can retrieve the names, which happen to be `ids` for this model using

```
newTodo.tags.idArr
```

which is hacky and unacceptable.

The test fails and this is my console output for

```
console.log(newTodo.tags)

 //OUTPUT
 QuerySet {
   ...
   idArr: ['testing', 'nice', 'cool']
   ...
 }

console.log(newTodo.tags.forEach, newTodo.tags.map)

//OUTPUT
[ Function forEach] [Function map]

console.log(newTodo.tags.toRefArray())

//OUTPUT
[undefined, undefined, undefined]

console.log('Print all tags')
newTodo.tags.forEach(tag => {
  console.log('Prints a tag')
  console.log(tag)
})

newTodo.tags.map(tag => {
  console.log('Prints a tag 2')
  console.log(tag)
  return tag
})

//OUTPUT
Prints all tags

console.log(newTodo.tags.withModels)

//Output is a QuerySet

newTodo.tags.withModels.map(tag => {
  console.log('mapping over tag models')
  console.log(tag)
  return tag
}
```

In response to @markerikson comment:

```
case CREATE_TODO:
    const tags = payload.tags.split(',')
    const trimmed = tags.map(tag => tag.trim())
    trimmed.forEach(tag => Tag.create(tag))
    break
```

in the `Tag` model handles a string inside the reducer. Code for both the `Todo` and `Tag` is [here](https://hastebin.com/iwojelizud.scala)

Comment: How are you creating the tags?  If you're trying to insert them as "just" strings, that won't work.  The Tag entries need to be models themselves.  An example might look like: `{id : 1, value : "testing"}`.  Can you link your entire code, or at least a large relevant chunk of it?

Comment: @markerikson I have updated the question with the Models, the idAttribute for the `Tag` is the `name` property. So, we might need to do` { name: 'testing' }` Also, the `Tag` reducer should handle `CREATE_TODO` and split the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment: you're not creating the Tag instances properly.  it looks like you're passing each individual tag string straight to `Tag.create()`, so that it's like `Tag.create("testing")`.  Instead, you need to pass an *object*, like `Tag.create({name : "testing"})`.